# My threading function causes flask to hang

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, python-multithreading

I'm very new to Flask so please bear with me.

So I'm working with an app that deals with a function that will take 30 minutes to complete (burn in test for a QA suite). Because this takes so long I'd like to have the app launch a "loading..." screen so the user isn't just staring at a hanging site for 30 minutes. I did some searching around and found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363505/python-flask-returning-a-html-page-while-simultaneously-performing-a-function). Which I have set up in my own way as such (only necessary functions shown)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import subprocess
import tests
from threading import Thread

app = Flask(__name__)

def async_slow_function(test, arguments):
    thr = Thread(target=test, args=arguments)
    thr.start()
    print("Thread starting...")
    return thr

@app.route('/strobe')
def strobe():
    print(async_slow_function(tests.strobe, ""))
    return index()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

However, this setup for me still has the app hanging while the test is running. Even when the test is complete the app still hangs. Which leaves me to believe that the thread is still running.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Just in case anyone in the future has the same issue as I did, below is my updated code that works.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import subprocess
import tests
from threading import Thread

app = Flask(__name__)

def async_slow_function(test, argue):
    if argue != None:
        thr = Thread(target=test, args=[argue])
    else:
        thr = Thread(target=test)
    thr.start()
    return thr

@app.route('/strobe')
def strobe():
    async_slow_function(tests.strobe, None)
    return render_template('testing.html')

@app.route('/fade')
def fade(): 
    async_slow_function(tests.fade, None)
    return render_template('testing.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

It had something to do with me returning the index() function. Instead I just rendered my testing template.